# Complementary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be function. If there exists only $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and I consider the set
$$A:=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}\; ; \; x<x_0 \; \text{and} \: f(s)<0,\; \forall \; s \in (x,x_0)\},$$
then, what is the $A$ complementary? That is, what is $A^C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to negate the condition for membership in $A$. So for $A$ we can say the conditions are $P \wedge Q$, where $P=x <x_0$ and $Q=\forall \, x < x_0, \, \forall s \in (x,x_0), \,\, f(s)<0$.

$$\neg(P \wedge Q)=\neg P \vee \neg Q.$$
So $\neg P= x \geq x_0$ and $\neg Q=\exists\,\, x<x_0, \,\, \exists s \in (x,x_0), \,\, f(s)\geq 0$

Thus
$$A^c=\{x \in \Bbb{R}\, | \, x \geq x_0 \text{ OR } \exists \, x<x_0, \,\, \exists s \in (x,x_0), \,\, f(s)\geq 0\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x $ be a real.

$$x\in A \iff$$
$$x<x_0 \; and \; (\forall s\in(x,x_0))\; f(s)<0$$

the negation is

$$x\in A^C \iff $$
$$x\ge x_0 \; or \Bigl(\; x<x_0 \;and \; (\exists s\in (x,x_0))\; :\; f(s)\ge 0\Bigr)$$